# Variable Type Issue For Parameter? - Powershell

Tags: powershell, parameters, active-directory, powershell-5.0

I am trying to run the below code to search for inactive user accounts in an OU.  It seems like the type of variable I'm using may not be able to used with parameters.  Does that seem correct and if so what type of variable should I be using?

```
$scope = "-UsersOnly" 

$accounts = Search-ADAccount -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=testLab02,DC=test,DC=local" -AccountInactive -TimeSpan ([timespan]7D) $scope
    foreach($account in $accounts){
        If ($noDisable -notcontains $account.Name) {
            Write-Host $account
            #Disable-ADAccount -Identity $account.DistinguishedName -Verbose $whatIf | Export-Csv $logFile
        }
    }
```

I receive the below error:

[image]

Search-ADAccount : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-UsersOnly'.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Disable-ADAccounts.ps1:63 char:21
+ ... $accounts = Search-ADAccount -SearchBase $OU.DistinguishedName -Accou ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Search-ADAccount], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SearchADAccount

However, if I run the command manually without variables it works as expected:

```
Search-ADAccount -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=testLab02,DC=test,DC=local" -AccountInactive -TimeSpan ([timespan]7D) -UsersOnly
```

[image]

Comment: Screenshots of PowerShell error messages are **really** hard on those of us who are colorblind and have trouble seeing the red on blue.  Maybe post the text instead?

Comment: Sorry about that, please see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `$scope = "-UsersOnly"`

You can't pass a (switch) *parameter* stored in a variable that way - it'll invariably be treated as a (positional) *argument*, which explains the error you saw; with *directly* passed arguments, only *unquoted, literal* tokens such as `-UsersOnly` are recognized as parameter names.

You can use [`splatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) to pass parameters via variables, which in your case means:

```
# Define a hash table of parameter values.
# This hash table encodes switch parameter -UsersOnly
$scope = @{ UsersOnly = $true } # [switch] parameters are represented as Booleans

# Note the use of sigil @ instead of $ to achieve splatting
Search-ADAccount @scope -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=testLab02,DC=test,DC=local" -AccountInactive -TimeSpan ([timespan]7D)
```

- `$scope` is defined as a [`hash table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (`@{ ... }`) whose entries represent *parameter name-value pairs*.

  - Here, only *one* parameter name-value pair is defined:

    - Parameter name `-UsersOnly` (the entry key must be defined *without* the `-` sigil) ...
    - ... with value `$true`, which for a `[switch]` (flag) parameter is equivalent to *passing* the parameter; `$false` is typically<sup>[1]</sup> equivalent to *omitting* it.
- To pass the parameter values represented by hashtable `$scope` to a command via [`splatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting), sigil `@` instead of `$` must be used, i.e, `@scope` in this case.

---

<sup>[1] A command can technically distinguish between a switch being *omitted* and it being passed with value `$false`, and on occasion that results in different behavior, notably with the common `-Confirm` parameter, where `-Confirm:$false` *overrides* the `$ConfirmPreference` preference variable.</sup>